# Incorrect generating of service reference

Tags: c#, wcf, servicecontract

I have class `Request` derived from `Dictionary<string, string>`. It has additional fields.
Then I have Service Contract: `string MakeRequest(Request request);`
After that I generate Service Reference for this contract. But VS by some reason generates next code:

```
string MakeRequest(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> request);
```

My question is how to tell VS that I want derived class and not base.

Comment: This might help you https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2682b808-efed-4f7d-89b1-c26a777565b4/accept-derived-classes-in-service-method?forum=wcf

Comment: Have you tagged your class `Request` with `[DataContract]` (and any properties etc. in it with `[DataMember]`)?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is possible. `Dictionary` support seems to be intrinsic. `Dictionary` is not a type understood by SOAP so it can't be serialized literally. For example it does not have a `[DataContract]` attribute. A derived type (maybe with custom fields) could not be serialized.

Deriving from `Dictionary` is a bad idea anyway. You probably should either derive from `IDictionary` and wrap a Dictionary exposing it as a property:

```
class MyDict { public Dictionary<...> Items; }
```